# Saving XML Data in Python with identical field names

Tags: python, xml

So I've imported this XML file to Python and I'm trying to save specific values from it to a new dataframe. The problem is, all the values have the same identifier "attribute." The values I want to save are the "id" and "value." Below is what the XML file looks like"

```
<Report>
    <summaries>
        <attributes>
          <id>variable1</id>
          <value>000</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
          <id>variable2</id>
          <value>005</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
          <id>variable3</id>
          <value>00002012</value>
```

I want the dataframe to look like this:

```
variable1    variable2    variable3
        0            5         2012
```

Here is my code so far:

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(str(xml)))
root = tree.getroot()

for id in root.iter('id'):     
    id = id.text
    print(id)

for value in root.iter('value'):     
    value = value.text
    print(value)
```

But after this I don't know a good command to call specific lines and return the text for the id and values.

Comment: Use elementtree xpath to find the attributes elements, and then the id and value in the element. Read the elementtree docs for some xpath examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the structure of XML is constant, we can use one-liner to create a DataFrame

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml = '''
<Report>
    <summaries>
        <attributes>
          <id>variable1</id>
          <value>000</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
          <id>variable2</id>
          <value>005</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
          <id>variable3</id>
          <value>00002012</value>
        </attributes>
    </summaries>
</Report>'''


root = ET.fromstring(xml)
df = pd.DataFrame({k.find("id").text:[k.find("value").text] for k in root.iterfind(".//attributes")})
```

Which outputs

```
>>> df
  variable1 variable2 variable3
0       000       005  00002012
```

To cast to integer

```
>>> df2 = df.astype(int)
>>> df2
   variable1  variable2  variable3
0          0          5       2012
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is what I needed. Is there something I can add to the code to handle any occurrences of 'N/A' values? When I ran your answer I got the following error from a different XML file: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @Kardinol We need to see the data

Comment: <Report>
    <summaries>
        <attributes>
          <id>variable1</id>
          <value>000</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
          <id>variable2</id>
          <value>005</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
          <id>variable3</id>
          <value>N/A</value>

Comment: I'm sorry about the format, I don't know how to post the data for you to see but it's the same format as the example above, but for this file, variable3  has a value of 'N/A'

Comment: @Kardinol you need to open another question.